# Which IOC runs in Medium Trust Having Issues with Ninject 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, inversion-of-control

I can't seem to get past the security excpetion with my current container, Ninject. I have signed all my libs etc.. Ninject just won't work. So I pose this question:

What containers work out of the box without having to be rebuilt from source, in a medium trust shared hosting environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) is one example of a DI framework that works in medium trust.

This being said IIRC Ninject 2 works in medium trust as well. You could try setting the `UseReflectionBasedInjection` switch to `true` which will instruct Ninject to use reflection instead of lightweight code generation. You may also look at [this thread](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/issues/15).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read that thread. Very unpredictable solution and breaks some other things potentially. I have switched to UNITY, ugh. I want my Ninject back!! Now I have to figure out lifetime management since UNity seems oblivious to web applications.

Comment: I marked this as an answer since it lead me to find a hosting provider that supports full trust. The fact that one would have to change the way an application functions for a hosting provider is crazy. Ninject works great, i am sticking with it. I also always accept Darin's answers because he is smarter than I am.. LOL